# i want to show all the projects title from the database but it shows only one project . why?

Tags: php, laravel

the ProjectsController class :

```
class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $projects= Project::all();
      // return $projects;
        return view('projects.index',['projects'=> $projects]);
    }
}
```

this is the index.blade.php class :

```
<h1>my Projects</h1>
    @foreach($projects as $project)
        <li>{{ $project->title }}</li>
    @endforeach
```

this is the route :

```
Route::get('/projects','ProjectsController@index');
```

but it shows only one project title !!!!!

[image]

Comment: whats the contents of `$projects`?

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina: $projects= Project::all(); and the model Project is empty, $projects must containes all the projects from the database but it shows only one

Comment: I think Miroslav means is can you `var_dump($projects)` to see its content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there is more than just one project in the database? Try `dd($projects)` in the controller to confirm that the returned result has more than one record. Next, are you sure you're looking at, and editing, the right view file?